# pdf file displays as text/html instead of application/pdf

Tags: php, pdf, http-headers, content-type

I'm trying to display a .pdf file in a php application. It works perfectly well on my local development setup but on production, the same code displays the pdf as garbled text.

These are the request headers i'm using:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET["f"];
$filename = 'contrato.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' .$filename. '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile($file);
?>
```

These are the production response headers according to chrome:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 03 Apr 2017 21:31:19 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=189
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

On the development setup, the response headers are these:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Disposition:inline; filename="contrato.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Mon, 03 Apr 2017 21:33:44 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) PHP/5.5.8
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.8
```

Could it be due to the apache settings?

Comment: Just to check: The garbled output starts with something like: `%PDF-1.3`? You need to switch on error reporting in PHP. See if anything has been sent before you send your headers.

Comment: Probably some proxy or server changing it, or your request to change headers is being denied by PHP. Check your errors: http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1255289

Comment: Yes, it starts with something like that. Errors are off on production, good idea to turn them on to debug this.

Comment: As suggested by @KIKOSoftware something is being sent to the browser first, even a single space will cause it to not work.

Comment: Also I hope that's not your real code. This will allow someone to read ANY file that apache can read, such as your entire PHP source code

Comment: Don't forget that in some case an UTF-8 BOM can also cause problems with sending headers. You cannot even see it.

Comment: @Augwa you were right, a space was being sent before the headers. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I think it's the error in this line:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

Note the small letter **t**

this line should be like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

also note that you are reading a file using the $_GET["f"]
this is wrong, instead read the file from $filename variable.
Change the last line to :

```
readfile($filename);
```

Anyway here's the correction of your code:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET["f"];
$filename = 'abc.pdf';
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' .$file. '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile($filename);
?>
```

Comment: I also noticed that and tried with the uppercase T, it didn't make any difference. Regarding the filename variable, i don't think its the issue because i can access the file, the problem is it appears as text/html.

Comment: instead of reading the $filename, you are reading $file, which is a parameter sent by the users.

use:  readfile($filename);  in the last line.

Comment: @Muhaimen *"instead of reading the $filename, you are reading $file"* - probably that is exactly what the op wants, sending a file given by a parameter with a header claiming the given file name. In that case this may be a security issue though as the parameter is not checked.

Comment: @mkl, you´re right, $file contains the path and name of the file to be displayed. thanks.

Comment: @P.Hoffmann ,  if this is your code, and you let the users to send you the real path of the file to be read, then this is a bad way of implementation.